# RequestLogger - Waiting for requests[0].response

Tags: testing, xmlhttprequest, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When logging requests using the RequestLogger, the requests array records the immediate response which isn't always present if the response takes more than a few seconds to return.

Is there a way to wait for the statusCode to return before the request gets logged, or a way to get the statusCode for the specified request when it has been returned?

Using `await t.expect(logger.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();` didn't work for me.

Comment: The code `await t.expect(logger.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();` looks correct. Could you please provide a simple example which I can run locally?

Comment: You won't be able to access the url outside my work network.  However good to know that the await statement should work. Thanks.

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798820/testcafe-requestlogger-how-to-wait-for-all-responses-to-return-before-doing-an