# TestCafe RequestLogger - How to wait for all responses to return before doing an assertion on each request object

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

See the attached screenshot. I have a RequestLogger that captures all the requests to `/api/dynamic_reporting/filters/*/find` endpoint.

The issue is that when I do an assertion `await t.expect(dynamicReportingFindRequest.requests[1].response.statusCode).eql(200,'Did not get 200 OK response')`, I get an error `Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined` because the xhr is still pending for `requests[1], requests[2]...` and hasn't completed yet.

How do I wait for all responses to return before doing an assertion on the requests?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution based on the idea from the [testcafe RequestLogger not intercepting api calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677238/testcafe-requestlogger-not-intercepting-api-calls) question:

Here is simple node.js server:

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url.indexOf('test') > -1) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.write('rest');
            res.end();
        }, 10000);
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(`<button onclick="fetch('http://localhost:8082/test'); setTimeout(() => { fetch('http://localhost:8082/test'); }, 100);setTimeout(() => { fetch('http://localhost:8082/test'); }, 200)">button</button>`);

        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8082);
```

Click on the button sends 3 requests.

And the test code is the following:

```js
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger(/test/);

fixture `Getting Started`
    .page `http://localhost:8082`;

test.requestHooks(logger)('My first test', async t => {
    await t.click('button');

    while (logger.requests.find(r => !r.response || r.response.statusCode !== 200))
        await t.wait(1000);

    console.log(logger.requests.length);
    console.log(logger.requests.filter(r => r.response.statusCode === 200).length);
});
```

Comment: Excellent solution @Alex Kamaev. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: So if I use the following snippet (using the smart assertions as per documentation
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402837/guides/basic-guides/assert#smart-assertion-query-mechanism) before running assertions on the responses, am I not given any certainty that each logger requests will also contain a response object with _statusCode_, _headers_, _body_, _timestamp_ ?

`await t.expect(logger.count(() => true)).gte(0, 'There is no logs found');`

I want to run the snippet before asserting the responses is because I want to make sure that a response is actually received.